# Org-mode: Latex Export. I would like borders for examples

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to have borders for my examples.  I am using the code

```
   #+ATTR_LATEX: :options frame=single
   #+begin_example 
   - stuRollNo:String
   # stuName:name
   + subject:Subject
     marks:Double
   #+end_example
```

However, when exported to PDF, I am not getting the expected single line border.  Any idea where I am doing the mistake?

Comment: Where did you see that option described? I cannot find anything in the manual about it.

Comment: I used it for `#+BEGIN_SRC` special block.  But I used `minted` there. I tried it for `#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE`,  but it didn't work.  From reddit, one gentleman, sent me this link.https://alhassy.github.io/org-special-block-extras/. But finding it difficult to understand.